# Do Views go to recycle bin?

Tags: list-view

I am using SharePoint 2013.

If I delete a view for a task I created does that view to go SharePoint's recycle bin like a task or document will? I'm guessing the answer is no, but I want to make sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) You are correct. The answer is No. Only 'data' is sent to recycle bin: lists/libraries, items/documents, and sites (though they go into a hidden recycle bin that only administrators can access).